# pregunta de python con listas

Tags: python

hola soy nuevo en esto queria ver si me podrian ayudar en lo siguiente;

```
import random

colores=["rojo","azul","amarillo","negro","blanco","celeste","verde","rosa"]
paises=["argentina","uruguay","brasil","cuba","venezuela"]

animales=["mono","jirafa","gato","vaca","jabali","elefante"]

todo=["uruguay","brasil","blanco","rojo","mono","vaca"]

salida=[]

elige=random.choice(todo)
```

como ven tengo 3 listas y una lista vacia, lo que quiero hacer es que elige me elija un elemento aletorio y solo 1 elemento aletorio de cada lista y me la guarde en la lista salida.si me podrian ayudar o orientarme mas o menos se los agradeceria mucho. desde ya Gracias.

Comment: ¿Te sirve algo como: `salida = [random.choice(colores), random.choice(paises), ...]` ?

Answer (score 1):

¿Por qué no unes las listas y haces un random.choice de cada una de ellas?

```
import random

colores=["rojo","azul","amarillo","negro","blanco","celeste","verde","rosa"]
paises=["argentina","uruguay","brasil","cuba","venezuela"]
animales=["mono","jirafa","gato","vaca","jabali","elefante"]

lista_final = [random.choice(colores), random.choice(paises), random.choice(animales)]

print(lista_final)
```

Resultado:

```
$ -> python3 random_element.py 
['blanco', 'argentina', 'elefante']
```

Entiendo que en todo estabas insertando las 3 listas, pero en ese caso solo cogerá un elemento.